# why does NSManagedObjectContext Queue execute on main thread?

Tags: ios, core-data

When I send a `performBlock` message to my MOC of type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, like this:

```
[self.privateManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    if ([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) {
        NSLog(@"executing on the main thread!!");        
    }
    …
}];
```

I find that, by default, this executes on the main thread. The conditional in the above code triggers, and the Issue Navigator indicates that execution is occurring on `Thread 1` in the `NSManagedObject Queue`.

This is very puzzling to me, because Apple tells us that "each thread must have its own entirely private managed object context." Given that an MOC of type `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` will use the main thread, doesn't it violate thread confinement for an MOC of type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` to use the main thread?

Is the execution of my code on the main thread normal? Have I misunderstood thread confinement? I understand that a queue is not necessarily tied to a particular thread, but in this case it seems the private MOC queue should at a minimum avoid the main thread, if not have a single go-to thread. I'm having some weird bugs, so I need to figure out what's going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This optimization is possible because `performBlockAndWait:` executes the block 
*synchronously*, i.e. the method does not return until the block has finished.
Therefore the block will not be executed in parallel with other operations on
the main thread.

(For the same reason, `dispatch_sync(queue, ...)` may execute a block on the main thread
instead of a separate thread.)

Comment: Yes, what this post describes is right, but does it give the question an answer?

Comment: @Chengjiong: I think I have answered the question. What do you think is missing?

Comment: you explained why the block in performBlockAndWait: was performed in main thread, but as I saw in the question, mkc842 wants to know why a NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType context can run on main thread, does this violate Apple's rule, also these are what I want to know.

Comment: @Chengjiong: NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType specifies that the context is associated with a private dispatch *queue*. A queue is not bound to a fixed *thread*. GCD can choose to execute blocks from a non-main queue on the main thread here, because there is no possibility that any other code executes on the main thread simultaneously. It is an optimization to reduce the number of thread switches.

Comment: Cool, you cleared my doubt. I have another question, wish you can help me:). The question is, I create a context with type NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType in the main thread, from Apple's doc, is this mean that I can only use the context and NSManagedObjects managed by it in main thread only?