# Why Quality of service set to background runs in main thread?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Why is the below code running in main thread although i have specified qos to background thread?

```
func testQueue(){

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.appcoda.myqueue",qos:.background)
    queue.sync {

        if Thread.isMainThread{
            print("is in main thread")
        }else{
            print("is i background thread")
        }
        for i in 100..<110 {
            print("Ⓜ️", i)
        }
    }
}

testQueue()
```

Whenever i try to run the method i get msg in console as `is in main thread`which should not be the case..I am reading in this article.

http://www.appcoda.com/grand-central-dispatch/

*See the Getting Started with dispatch queues section.*

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/22948558/1187415

Comment: That means it never gets execute in background or is it just sometimes may happen for optimization purpose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have specified a background *queue*, not a background *thread*. When you dispatch a task on a queue, GCD looks for a thread to run the task on.

Since you are using a synchronous dispatch, the main *queue* is blocked, leaving the main *thread* free to perform work, so your task executes on the main thread.

- tasks dispatched on the main *queue* **will** run on the main *thread*
- tasks dispatched on another *queue* **may** run on the main *thread* or another *thread*

Comment: so strange...It would be good if we could create our own thread rather than lying on GCD Queues

Comment: Part of the point of GCD is that it abstracts away from threads. You can create NSThreads if you want, but there is no advantage over GCD queues in almost every case. It doesn't matter which thread your code runs on, the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the Solution :-**

Default for main thread is always **sync**, so no matter what queue you have created with what properties, it will always run in main thread when it is declared as **sync**.

[Refer this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OINZV.png)

Second thing Main thread can run in async as well and it will guarantees that this new task will execute sometime after the current method finishes.

Third thing is when you will try the same code with **async** then it will work fine.

[Refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgimE.png)

See the following code and figure it out :-

```
func testQueue(){

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.appcoda.myqueue",qos:.background, attributes:DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent)

    queue.sync {   //Sync will always create main thread

        if Thread.isMainThread{
            print("is in main thread")
        }else{
            print("is i background thread")
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async { //Main thread can be async
        if Thread.isMainThread{
            print("is in main thread")
        }else{
            print("is i background thread")
        }

    }

    if Thread.isMainThread { //default is Main thread sync
        for i in 100..<110 {
            print("Ⓜ️", i)
        }
    }
    else{
        print("is i background thread")
    }

    queue.async {   //Here your custom async thread will work
        if Thread.isMainThread{
            print("is in main thread")
        }else{
            print("is i background thread")
        }
    }

}

testQueue()
```