# Execution of dispatch_async execution (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var testArray:[String] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        doThis(nil)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func doThis(completion:(() -> Void)?) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
            if let completionBlock = completion {
                completionBlock()
            }

            self.testArray.append("first")
            print(self.testArray)
            if self.testArray == [] {
                print("has data")
            } else {
                print("null")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

---

Output:

```
["first"]
null
```

I was wondering why the array is `nil`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179358/concurrent-vs-serial-queues-in-gcd please look at this experiments..this will make you clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is not nil. It cannot be nil because nil is one case of `Optional`, and the array isn't declared `Optional`.

Presumably you are wondering why your program prints `null`. It prints `null` because the `if` condition is false. The `if` condition is `self.testArray == []`. It's false because the array is not empty.

Perhaps you have reversed the sense of the condition without realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your self.testArray is having items self.testArray == [] will be false. Also it will be much better to use self.testArray.count > 0 in case of check array items.