# How to update the NSProgressIndicator?

Tags: macos, swift3, nsprogressindicator, nsprogress

I have problem with `NSProgress`. The problem is that `NSProgressIndicator` is not updating during the process and showing only a small completed portion at the end of process.  The localizedDescription is also showing only at the end of the process, but as 100% completed.

So, I have a class with one method `findRepeatsWithProgressReporting`  using `NSProgress`

```
class TestProgress: NSObject, ProgressReporting
{
    let progress: Progress

    override init()
    {
        progress = Progress()
        super.init()
    }

    func findRepeatsWithProgressReporting(stringToSearch: String, minimalLength: Int, maximalLength: Int) -> [String]
    {
        var arrayOfRepeats = [String]()

        progress.totalUnitCount = Int64((minimalLength...maximalLength).count)

        for i in minimalLength...maximalLength
        {
            let arrayOfStrings = stringToSearch.chopString(stringOut: stringToSearch, length: i)
            let arrayOfUniqueStrings = Array(Set(arrayOfStrings))

            for each in arrayOfUniqueStrings
            {
                let arrayOfNSRanges = stringToSearch.searchForNSRangesOfStringInString(stringOut: stringToSearch, stringIn: each)

                var positions = String()

                if arrayOfNSRanges.count > 1
                {
                    for each1 in arrayOfNSRanges
                    {
                        let repeatStart = String(each1.location + 1)
                        let repeatEnd = String(each1.location + each1.length)
                        positions += "(" + repeatStart + "-" +  repeatEnd + ")"
                    }
                    let stringToShow = each + " " + positions
                    arrayOfRepeats.append(stringToShow)
                }
            }
            progress.completedUnitCount += 1
        }
        return  arrayOfRepeats
    }

}
```

Then, in `myVewContrloler` I  have parentProgress `repeatsProgress` having `totalUnitCount: 10` and have added the task of the method `findRepeatsWithProgressReporting`  as childProgress  to the parentProgress `repeatsProgress`  using  `repeatsProgress.becomeCurrent(withPendingUnitCount: 10)`.

```
private var progressObservationContext = 0

class myVewContrloler: NSViewController
{
    ...

    var testProgress = TestProgress ()
    var repeatsProgress = Progress() 

    @IBOutlet weak var repeatsSearchProgressBar: NSProgressIndicator!
    @IBOutlet weak var repeatsPercentText: NSTextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var minimalLength: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var maximalLength: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet var foundRepeats: NSTextView!

    @IBAction func actionFindRepeats(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        repeatsProgress = Progress(totalUnitCount: 10)

        let options : NSKeyValueObservingOptions = [.new, .old, .initial, .prior]
        repeatsProgress.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "fractionCompleted", options: options, context: &progressObservationContext)
        repeatsProgress.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "localizedDescription", options: options, context: &progressObservationContext)

        var arrayOfRepeats = [String]()

        repeatsProgress.becomeCurrent(withPendingUnitCount: 10)
        arrayOfRepeats = testProgress.findRepeatsWithProgressReporting(stringToSearch: stringToSearch, minimalLength: minimalLength.integerValue, maximalLength: maximalLength.integerValue)

        ...

        repeatsProgress.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "fractionCompleted")
        repeatsProgress.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "localizedDescription")

        repeatsProgress.resignCurrent()
    }
}
```

The last part is for KVO :

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
{
        guard context == &progressObservationContext else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        return
    }

    if keyPath == "fractionCompleted"
    {
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation{
                let progress = object as! Progress
                self.repeatsSearchProgressBar.doubleValue = progress.fractionCompleted
                self.repeatsPercentText.stringValue = progress.localizedDescription
        }
    }
}
```

I have added

```
print("Observed Something")
```

inside of the

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
{  ...
```

and what I see is two times printing the `"Observed Something"`immediately after start and six times at the end, no printing in between (as it expected to be for the updating process). What can be the reason ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a concurrency problem. Since `func actionFindRepeats(_ sender: AnyObject)` is running in the main thread, it's concurring with the UI updates, which affects the `NSProgressIndicator` directly.

See the last example of that answer for more details about that:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35810608/4370893

You can try adding all the content of your actionFindRepeats function into that block and see if it works:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    // qos' default value is ´DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default`
}
```

Reference for that block:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37806522/4370893

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I have made a test project only for the described above task, searching for repeats in string with progress reporting. All is done in AppDelegate. I have added as you suggested DispatchQueue.global().async and now in this project I see completed NSProgressIndicator and 100% completed localizedDescription at the end of the process. In main project, where I have separate Controller for the same task, and still the same incomplete NSProgressIndicator. And, in both projects I don't have updating NSProgressIndicator, no intermediate percentage.

Comment: And now in both projects, after the changes I have made, I also have the following waring in test project: 2017-03-24 19:39:55.202 Test2[3926:127626] Uncommited CATransaction. Set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to debug. CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.

Comment: I see that your advice was a right key for the problem, so thanks again, and I accept your answer.