# Async queue how it works with this sample code

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I have written a sample code for getting deep into the threading concepts as below.

```
print("a")
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
   print("b")
   DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
      print("c")
      DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        print("d")
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
         print("e")
        }
        print("f")
      }
      print("g")
   }
   print("h")
}
print("i")
```

OUTPUT

```
a
i
b
h
c
g
d
f
e
```

How the output seems like this. What is actually happening inside?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53582047/9086770

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic behaviors:

1. As the name implies an asynchronously dispatched queue is always executed **after** the enclosing scope – `{}` – exits.

   So `i` is printed before `b`, `h` is printed before `c` etc.
2. A dispatch queue works serial by default, all tasks are executed one after another

   So the consecutive order is `i - b - h - c - g - d - f - e`

Comment: `DispatchQueue.global` is a concurrent not serial a way from the fact that the op nestes the code which make it look serial in printing but not in run as consider making an api request

Answer (score 1):

The idea is any 2 lines 1 of them is

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async
```

the second will run first , so this

```
print("a")
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {  
 print("b")
}
print("i")
```

gives

```
a // comes first
i // printed first before queue as the queue dispatches the execution with some delay
b // printed second
```

Then go inside the async and apply the same rule

```
   DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
      print("c")
      DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {  
      print("d")
      }
      print("g")
   }
   print("h")


h

c

g

d
```

Answer (score 1):

On each DispatchQueue.global context was splitting up, and cost of dispatching higher than simple print, that's all.