# How do I use DispatchGroup in background thread?

Tags: swift

I have two functions (or tasks) that I want to run one after the other and i'm using DispatchGroup to track them and notify me when they're complete. Right now they're being done in the Main thread but I want to run these tasks in a background thread. How would I go about doing so? I've tried a few approaches but they either run simultaneously or I get an exception error after the first one completes. The following code performs the tasks one after the other but if I call Thread.current inside the functions I can see that they are being run in the Main thread.

```
@objc func doWorkFunctions(){
    taskGroup.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync {
        self.firstFunction {
            self.taskGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    taskGroup.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync {
        self.secondFunction {
            self.taskGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    taskGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("All tasks completed")
    }
}
```

If I use the following code they are run simultaneously but in the background thread.

```
@objc func doWorkFunctions(){
    taskGroup.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.firstFunction {
            self.taskGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    taskGroup.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.secondFunction {
            self.taskGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    taskGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("All tasks completed")
    }
}
```

I've been searching and searching but I can't seem to find an answer to my problem or clarity for that matter. Can someone provide some guidance as to what's going on here. These are the functions in question in case. They simulate a long task to practice tracking progress.

```
func firstFunction(completion: @escaping()->Void){
    print(Thread.current)
    if childProgressOne.isCancelled { return }
    for i in 1...5 {
        sleep(1)

        childProgressOne.completedUnitCount = Int64(i * 20)

        print("Child Progress One: \(childProgressOne.fractionCompleted)")
        print("Total Progress: \(totalProgress.fractionCompleted)")
    }
    completion()
}

func secondFunction(completion: @escaping()->Void){
    print(Thread.current)

    if childProgressTwo.isCancelled { return }
    for i in 1...5 {
        sleep(1)

        childProgressTwo.completedUnitCount = Int64(i * 20)

        print("Child Progress Two: \(childProgressTwo.fractionCompleted)")
        print("Total Progress: \(totalProgress.fractionCompleted)")
    }
    completion()
}
```

This also performs them in order but calling Thread.current inside the functions tells me they are being performed in the Main thread even though they are being called to a background thread.

```
 @objc func doWorkFunctions(){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync {
        self.taskGroup.enter()
        self.firstFunction {
            self.taskGroup.leave()
        }
        self.taskGroup.enter()
        self.secondFunction {
            self.taskGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    taskGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("All tasks completed")
    }
}
```

Comment: When you place them in the background thread, they will run simultaneously. I don't exactly get the problem.

Comment: @George_E I don't want them to run simultaneously. I want them to run in the background one after the other.

Comment: Does it work if you use the first block of code with the `sync` and put both in one `DispatchQueue` block?

Comment: That performs them one after the other but for some reason calling Thread.current inside the functions says it's still in the main thread.

Comment: @George_E updated question with suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure you need the `DispatchGroup` either - it can very easily cause a deadlock and I do not think it is needed (not very experienced with threads, so not 100% sure).

Comment: Are `firstFunction` and `secondFunction` asynchronous or synchronous functions?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper In the context of the main thread they are run asynchronous as a group. To each other they are synchronous, meaning one function has to finish for the other one to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given what you've described, I probably wouldn't use a dispatch group at all here. I'd just chain the methods:

```
@objc func doWorkFunctions() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.firstFunction {
            self.secondFunction {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("All tasks completed")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

But assuming you have a good reason for a group here, what you need to do is to use `.notify` to synchronize them. `.notify` says "when the group is empty, submit this block to this queue."

```
@objc func doWorkFunctions(){
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)

    taskGroup.enter()
    queue.async {
        self.firstFunction {
            self.taskGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    taskGroup.notify(queue: queue) {
        self.taskGroup.enter()

        self.secondFunction {
            self.taskGroup.leave()
        }

        self.taskGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("All tasks completed")
        }
    }
}
```

(You probably don't need `taskGroup` to be an instance property here. You could make it a local variable and have fewer `self.` references required. Each block has a reference to the group, so it will live until all the blocks have completed.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply Rob. The first worked out just fine for the intended purpose but the second one ended with an NSException. In both cases the functions were performed one after the other and in a background thread but in the second I get an error right after "All tasks completed" is printed out in the debugger. I suppose that I could use the first approach just fine for what i intended the code to perform which is basically tracking progress of both functions individually and overall. i'm still trying to wrap my head around DispatchGroups and how they are used and for what.

Comment: What exception? (Did you remember the first `.enter()` call at line 4? That's the most likely mistake.)

Comment: I realized that the exception was being thrown because I was working in a class and there was an issue with the outlet from the button used to trigger the method. In a simple playground your solution works perfectly using groups. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is run two functions in serial in the background, then all you need to do is execute them in order in the same task within the same queue. There isn't any need to get fancy at all.

You can plug this into a playground and mess around with it:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

func firstFunction(completion: @escaping() -> Void) {
    for i in 1...5 {
        sleep(1)
        print(i, Thread.current)
    }
    completion()
}

func secondFunction(completion: @escaping() -> Void) {
    for i in 1...5 {
        sleep(1)
        print(i + 100, Thread.current)
    }
    completion()
}

func doWorkFunctions() {

    let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serial")
    //let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default) <-- this will produce the same result

    serialQueue.async {
        firstFunction(completion: {
            print("first function done")
        })
        secondFunction(completion: {
            print("second function done")
        })
    }

}

doWorkFunctions()
```

Whether you execute these two functions in a serial queue or a concurrent queue, and whether you dispatch them in sync or async, is trivial as far as your question is concerned if you place them in the same task in the same queue. If you, however, separated the two functions into two separate tasks (or queues, for that matter), then serialization and concurrency become a factor. However, as a caveat, the term "concurrent" is relative. All tasks executed through dispatch queues (serial or concurrent) are concurrent to the main thread. But when we talk about them in the context of dispatch queues, we almost always mean concurrent to other tasks.

Read this to get a better understanding of what exactly queueing is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53582047/9086770

Comment: Thanks so much! That information really helps out. Apples documentation is very limited in this regard. Your solution works perfectly for the intended purposes as well. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Great read form the link. You summed it up perfectly and made it way more clear. Thanks again.

Comment: It's surprising that this would work in live code. This example runs `completion` synchronously before returning, which means it's not a completion handler at all (completion handlers are run after an asynchronous operation completes, after returning). A more typical example would enclose the entire body of `firstFunction` and `secondFunction` in a `DispatchQueue.async` call on a queue you don't control, in which case `secondFunction` will start before `firstFunction` finishes.

Comment: Nothing surprising here--two functions were placed into a single task into the same queue and were executed in serial. There isn't anything that requires a completion block to be called on async operations (before or after the function returns) to be considered a completion block (true of all callbacks in all languages AFAIK). A completion block is nothing more than a block run after the operation’s main task is done. Whether they're typically used in async is something else, but their sole purpose is to notify the end of an operation--on the main thread, in the background, in sync, in async.

Comment: The common misconception here seems to be, that function `firstFunction` and function `secondFunction ` ought to be _asynchronous_, which the `@escaping`  modifier for the completion handler indicates. However, the simulated functions are indeed _synchronous_.  @nard ‘s approach only works for synchronous functions. Now, the questions is, are the _actual_ functions asynchronous or synchronous? In case the actual functions are _asynchronous_ @RobNapier's is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a combination of the first two answers. I used what @nard posted in the second answer but also using DispatchGroup. I realize in this scenario DispatchGroup isn't really needed but if in case it was, this would be a way to do it. Thanks to @Rob Napier and @nard for the guidance.

```
import UIKit
func workOne(completion: @escaping ()->Void){
    print(Thread.current)
    for i in 1...4{
        sleep(1)
        print(i)
    }
    completion()
}
func workTwo(completion: @escaping ()->Void){
    print(Thread.current)
    for i in 5...8{
        sleep(1)
        print(i)
    }
    completion()
}
func doWork(){
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    workOne {
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    workTwo {
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print(Thread.current)
        print("completed!")
    }
}
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
    doWork()
}
```